# Fixing C code and argument fixes from compilation error

Tags: c, arrays, string, gcc

I am encountering these errors, when I compile my code. Also I think the braces are in the wrong position. May you guys help me to verify my for loops have been formatted correctly and debug the code. The aim of my code is to display duplicate letters and occurrences of the repeated letters.

This is the compilation error:

```
secfun@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ gcc -Wall -Werror -o -ansi letter.out   letter.c -lm
letter.c: In function ‘main’:
letter.c:14:1: error: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but   argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[(sizetype)(i)]’ [-Werror=format=]
scanf("%s", &inp);
^
letter.c: At top level:
letter.c:22:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
{
^
letter.c:46:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
{
 ^
 cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

 void printDuplicate(const char inp[], char duplicate);
 void printOccurrence(const char inp[], char occurrence);

 int main(void)
 {
 int i;
 char inp[i];
 char duplicate;
 char occurrence; 
 printf("Enter a word:\n");  
 scanf("%s", &inp);
 printf("Duplicate letter: %c, Occurences: %c", duplicate, occurrence);
 printDuplicate(inp, duplicate);
 printOccurrence(inp, occurrence);
 return 0;
 }

 void printDuplicate(const char inp[], char duplicate);
 {

  int i, j;
  int k=1;

  /* For loop finding duplicate characters */ 

  for (i = 0; i < duplicate; i++) 
  { 
  for (j = i + 1; j < duplicate; j++)
  {
  if (inp[i] == inp [j])
  {
  if (k == 1 && inp[j] != '\0')
  {
  inp[j] = '\0';
  k++;
  }
  k=1;
  }
  }
  }
  }

  void printOccurrence(const char inp[], char occurrence);
  {

  int freq = 0;

  for(i = 0; inp[i] != '\0'; ++i)
  {
  if(occurrence == inp[i])
  ++freq;
 }
 }
```

Comment: `i` isn't initialized, but you still use it to declare your array inp. And after, scanf wait a `char*` for a "%s", but you give `char **` (yes, it's an aproximation). Take off the "&". Didn't read much further, you have to read your compilator warning and fix them.

Comment: You should learn how to indent C code.

Comment: If your code does not even compile, then you don't have a bug, you have a compilation error and consequently you aren't talking about debugging.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is here:

```
...
int i;          // here i is not yet initialized, it contains an undetermined value
char inp[i];    // so here you declare an array with an 
                // undetermined length which is not good
...
```

Then there is an extra `;` at the end of this line (where you intend to define the function):

```
void printDuplicate(const char inp[], char duplicate);
                                                     ^ remove this
```

Same here:

```
void printOccurrence(const char inp[], char occurrence);
```

Then `i` is not declared at all in `printOccurrence`.

This is also wrong:

```
scanf("%s", &inp);
```

You need this:

```
scanf("%s", inp);
```

`inp` is already a pointer to `char`.

And last but not least: this is invalid, because `inp[]` is `const`

```
inp[j] = '\0';
```

There may be even more problems.

You probably should get back to your C text book.